# How to calculate the ERC20 token price with respective to cents?

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps

Initially, I have a ERC20 token price as 10 cents..
so,to sum it up.

1 token = **10 cents**

10 tokens = **100 cents**/1 dollar and so on...!

How to use cents in Wei form in solidity to calculate the token price

```
   function buy_token(address _to, uint256 numberOfTokens) external payable  returns(uint256) {            
        require(numberOfTokens > 0);
        require(balances[owner] >= numberOfTokens);
        require(balances[_to] + numberOfTokens >= balances[_to]);
        
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(numberOfTokens);
        balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numberOfTokens);
        emit Transfer(owner, msg.sender, numberOfTokens);
  }
```

Now when someone tries to buy token, calculate the amount of tokens based on the amount input..

Comment: Where exactly in your function are "cents" involved in any manner???

Comment: I have a ERC20 token which I set up a initial price of 10 cents..Now what I want is, whenever someone try to buy the token from My DAPP,  They should input Ether and me converted those ether to cents and gave them as much token as ether inputed..

Comment: "whenever someone try to buy the token from My DAPP, They should input Ether and me converted those ether to cents and gave them as much token as ether inputed"

I think what you mean here is that you want to see how many cents their Ether is worth and then give them the respective amount of tokens. To do that you need some way to get the ethereum price, for which you can use something called an *oracle*, examples of which are Chainlink and Coinbase's price oracle.

I hope this gets you on the right track, however, if I'm misunderstanding you please let me know.

Comment: Actually, you should probably use the MakerDAO price oracle, which seems to be the best. https://developer.makerdao.com/feeds/

Comment: Yes you get it accurately..I have a way to get the ethereum price by API and send it as an argument  to the buy function defined in solidity(either in the form of wei or ether)..What is oracle??